# Creating a Pretty RevTex Table with Long Equations

Tags: tables, equations, revtex

I want to create a large RevTex compatible table that has a variable name in the first column and its expression in the right column. An example with only two rows (more in reality) is below:

```
\documentclass[aps, pre, reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{table*}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{p{1in} p{6in}}
Variable & Expression \\
\hline
$\alpha$ & $\begin{aligned} &-2 q_1^2 (6 \alpha _4 A_1^4-A_1^2 (\alpha _2+20 \alpha _4 A_2^2+32 \alpha _4 A_3 A_2-4 \alpha _3 A_3+40 \alpha _4 A_3^2)+ \\ & 2 (6 \alpha _4 A_2^4+A_2^2 (\alpha _2+4 A_3 (4 \alpha _3+9 \alpha _4 A_3))+2 A_3^2 (\alpha _2+6 \alpha _4 A_3^2))) \end{aligned}$ \\

$\gamma$ & $\begin{aligned} &\frac{1}{3} q_1^4 (12 \alpha _4 A_1^4-A_1^2 (\alpha _2+4 (11 \alpha _4 A_2^2+32 \alpha _4 A_3 A_2-7 \alpha _3 A_3+58 \alpha _4 A_3^2))+ \\ & 2 (24 \alpha _4 A_2^4+A_2^2 (\alpha _2+204 \alpha _4 A_3^2+40 \alpha _3 A_3)+8 A_3^2 (\alpha _2+12 \alpha _4 A_3^2))) \end{aligned}$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What is the simplest way to make this look nice? The obvious problems are:

1. The awkward white column between `$\gamma$` and its expression
2. How the fraction `$\frac{1}{3}$` goes outside the gray.
3. The exponents in the first line don't have enough space.

Answer (score 1):

i would:

- use `tabularx` for table environment
- not use colored rows
- in table body separate rows with tiny `Xhline{0.1pt}` from the package `makecell`
- for vertical spaces above/below cell content use macro`\makegapedcells` from the package `makecell`:

  ```
  \documentclass[aps, pre, reprint]{revtex4-1}
  \usepackage{mathtools}
  \usepackage{makecell,tabularx}
  \setcellgapes{3pt}

  %---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
  \usepackage{showframe}
  \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
  \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%

  \begin{document}
      \begin{table*}
  \makegapedcells
  \setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c X}
     \Xhline{0.8pt}
  Variable    &   Expression      \\
     \hline
  $\alpha$
      &  $\begin{multlined}[0.95\linewidth]
          -2 q_1^2 (6 \alpha_4 A_1^4-A_1^2 (\alpha_2+20 \alpha_4 A_2^2+32 \alpha_4 A_3 A_2-4 \alpha_3 A_3+40 \alpha_4 A_3^2) + \\
          2 (6 \alpha_4 A_2^4+A_2^2 (\alpha_2+4 A_3 (4 \alpha_3+9 \alpha_4 A_3))+2 A_3^2 (\alpha_2+6 \alpha_4 A_3^2)))
          \end{multlined}$          \\
      \Xhline{0.1pt}
  $\gamma$
      &   $\begin{multlined}[0.95\linewidth]
          \frac{1}{3} q_1^4 (12 \alpha_4 A_1^4-A_1^2 (\alpha_2+4 (11 \alpha_4 A_2^2+32 \alpha_4 A_3 A_2-7 \alpha_3 A_3+58 \alpha_4 A_3^2))+ \\
          2 (24 \alpha_4 A_2^4+A_2^2 (\alpha_2+204 \alpha_4 A_3^2+40 \alpha_3 A_3)+8 A_3^2 (\alpha_2+12 \alpha_4 A_3^2)))
          \end{multlined}$          \\
      \Xhline{0.8pt}
  \end{tabularx}
      \end{table*}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)